# Translation in odoo 10

Tags: odoo, odoo-10

i need to add translation for following modules, purchase, sales and accounting for Arabic. I found Arabic translation in odoo, but its not completed. I have exported *.pot file for purchase module. and placed it in my custom module  ***mymodule/i18n/purchase.po***(i replaced extension as *.po). And added msgstr in *.po file.
Now is the problem. i don't know how to use this modified *.po file. Pls help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally found solution.

1. Export Translation:

   1. Choose language, in my case Arabic.
   2. File format : PO
   3. Modules to export (ex: sales, stock, invoicing etc).
   4. Click on the Export button and download ar_SY.po file

2.Change `msgstr` in *.po file.

3. Put that file in `mymodule/i18/ar_SY.po.
4. Upgrade the module.

Answer (score 1):

For add translation in custom module following these steps:

1. Load a Translation (Settings >> Translation)
2. Open: Translated Terms
3. Search and Update terms in Odoo Front-End.
4. Export Translation : While export select your module in "Apps To Export"

Download po file and add into your module.

Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks Nikunj.. In step 4, which module i suppose to select?  i selected mycustom module. and downloaded pot file. in that file contains no translations.

Comment: When you load translation then system will add your custom module terms into systems.
After  load translation your module terms are create under 'Translated Terms' ?